# Align opamp to node, not node to opamp output

Tags: circuitikz, alignment

I found alot on aligning nodes to opamp outputs. But assuming there is a node in tikzpicture and i would like to place a opamp, such that its input align with the node.

How would i do it?

Example us case, would like to connect C1 to the positive input of the opamp.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % Loading circuitikz with siunitx option

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.2}% defines arrow's distance from nodes
    \ctikzset{voltage/distance from line=.02}% defines arrow's distance from wires
    \ctikzset{voltage/bump b/.initial=.1}% defines arrow's curvature

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw
    node[op amp,yscale=-1] (opamp) {}

    node[ocirc, left=3cm of opamp.+] (B) {}
    node[ocirc, below=5cm of B] (A) {}

    %node[op amp,yscale=-1] (opamp1) {}
    coordinate[right=0.5cm of opamp.out] (tmpout1)
    node[circ, below=2cm of tmpout1] (div1) {}
    (tmpout1 |- A) coordinate (tmpgndout1)
    coordinate[left=0.5cm of opamp.-] (opamp1-)

    (B) -- (opamp.+)
    (A) -- (tmpgndout1)
    (opamp.-) -- (opamp1-) -- (opamp1- |- div1) -- (div1)
    (opamp.out) -- (tmpout1) to[R, l=$R_1$] (div1) 
    (div1) to[R, l=$R_2$] (tmpgndout1)

    node[circ, right=2cm of tmpout1] (stage2in) {}
    (tmpout1) to[C,l=C$_1$] (stage2in)
    (stage2in) to[R,l=$R_3$] (stage2in |- A) -- (tmpgndout1)

    node[op amp,right=1cm of stage2in,yscale=-1] (opamp) {}

    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Active Envelope Detector Circuit}
    \label{fig:detector_circuit_active}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Try `\draw (stage2in)--(opamp.+);`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386909/logic-gates-with-circuitikz/386958?r=SearchResults&s=16|22.8208#386958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway, that you found solution yourself, I suggest you to see the following (to my opinion more consistent) code for your circuit:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % Loading circuitikz with siunitx option

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [op amp, yscale=-1] (oa1) {};
\draw   (oa1.+)     to[short,-o] ++ (-1,0)      coordinate (in)
        (oa1.out)   to [R=$R_1$,*-*] ++ (0,-2)  coordinate (aux1) 
                    to [R=$R_2$,-*] ++ (0,-2)      
        (oa1.out)   to [C=$C_1$,-*] ++ (2,0)    coordinate (aux2)
                    to [R=$R_3$,-*] ++ (0,-4)   coordinate (aux3)
                    to [short,-o] (in |- aux3)
        (aux1)      -|  (oa1.-)
        (aux2)      to[short]   ++ (1,0)
            node[op amp, yscale=-1,anchor=+] (oa2) {}
        (oa2.out) to [short,-o] ++ (1,0)        coordinate (out)
        (aux3)      to[short,-o]    (aux3 -| out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my MWE I focus only on image, so I use `standalone` document class. Scheme is complete as far you provide information about your circuit. It might help you in drawing your circuits.

Comment: this is much cleaner, i will try to understand and make use of it! Thank you

Comment: @Rico, I add missing connection point to circuit scheme. Now the scheme is more consistent (have all connections designated by black dots, other possibility is drop them out, i.e. remove from code all `-*` and `*-*`). Happy drawing with `circuitikz`!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which i think should be fine.

```
    node[op amp, right= 2cm of stage2in, anchor=+, yscale=-1] (opamp2) {}
```

Comment: I dont whink anything should be deleted. The question fill stay for others to find and use solutions provided by the thread.